# I want to use 3rd party library with conflicting selectors

Tags: angular, selector

My project uses two kinds of ng-select but they're different packages.
The problem is, they use the same selector, which is "ng-select"

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-select

I got error message : 
**More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: SelectComponent,NgSelectComponent**

Is there any way, like to customize the selector of one of them?
But I **can't** edit the selector in the node_modules.
And I'm **not** allowed to copy the package folder and put it in src/app folder.

Thank you very much